# Correct way to write this mysql query

Tags: mysql, sorting

I am trying to fetch data from mySQL table and show it in jsp,
I want to sort data in mySQL table alphabetically before fetching it.

I wrote this query which works perfectly. (shows sorted data)

```
String _snackListQuery ="SELECT snackID,snackName FROM snacklist ORDER BY snackName";
```

But This query is not working, (Shows nothing at all)

```
String _snackListQuery ="SELECT snackID,snackName FROM snacklist WHERE snackHideFlag=1 ORDER BY snackName";
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this a right query?

EDIT- my table goes like this

[image]

Comment: are there any items in snacklist where the snackHideFlag is 1? have you tried using the opposite: WHERE snackHideFlag != 0

Comment: seems fine does snackhideflag column exist? or snackHideFlag =1 exist?

Comment: snackHideFlag =1  exists, and i want to show data where snackHideFlag =1

Comment: Can you show an [SQLFidle](http://sqlfiddle.com) for that?

Comment: @Cube32 WHERE snackHideFlag != 0 is not working

Comment: Also, check the field's data type.

Comment: can you post the output of "SELECT snackHideFlag, count(snackID) FROM snacklist GROUP BY snackHideFlag" ? It really really looks like a data problem.

Comment: @JoeMinichino data type for snackHideFlag is boolean

Comment: right, in that case try using snackHideFlag IS 1 or IS true

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe - [I can't reproduced](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0476/1)

Comment: Just to know.. only `mysql` tag is needed.

Comment: @hims056 then whats wrong in my code? :s

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe - Nothing. Just adding `WHERE` condition will filter rows.

Comment: @hims056 strangely replacing 1 with true worked, i don't know why

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe - Not sure why but Flag=1 should work with `boolean` data type too. [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa088/3).

Comment: show your show create table output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS the type you're checking is a boolean, the proper operator to use is `IS`. Try replacing `snackHideFlag = 1` with `snackHideFlag IS true`

Comment: That worked! but technically snackHideFlag = 1 should also work right?

Comment: look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is). The comparison operator for boolean values is IS, 1 != true in mysql unless you use IS.